# I have 2 Lists of strings. How do I get a bool that tells me if one lists contains atleast one string from the other list ? (Using Lambda)

Tags: linq, list, lambda

This should be simple but I could not wrap my head around it.. Here is how I am doing it now but it seems so wasteful.

There is a

```
List<string> committees
```

and

```
List<string> P.committees
```

I just want to see if one list has any strings that are contained in the other.

```
  List<Person> listFilteredCommitteesPerson = new List<Person>();

            foreach (Person p in listFilteredPerson)
            {
                foreach (string strCommittee in p.Committees)
                {
                       if (committees.Contains(strCommittee))
                       {
                           listFilteredCommitteesPerson.Add(p);
                       }
                }
            }

            listFilteredPerson = listFilteredCommitteesPerson;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a boolean value:

```
var match = 
   committees.Intersect(listFilteredPerson.SelectMany(p => p.Committees)).Any();
```

If you want a collection of `Person` that have a match you can use:

```
var peopleThatMatch = 
    listFilteredPerson.Where(p => committees.Intersect(p.Committees).Any());
```

or:

```
var peopleThatMatch = 
    listFilteredPerson.Where(p => p.Committees.Any(s => committees.Contains(s)));
```

You might want to consider another collection type (e.g. `HashSet<T>`) for performance reasons if you have large collections.

Comment: That seemse to check all off them which can work.. Can you tell me how to modify this so it takes the collection listFilteredPerson and returns only the items that have this match ? That will save me the step of adding them manually to the new collection

Comment: @devdigital `Intersect` does use a `HashSet` internally.

Comment: great! thanks.. Can you break that 3rd statement into english?  I am trying to figure out how to read it.. I really need to find some C# lambda expression 101 book.

Comment: The third LINQ query says 'get me a collection of people where any of the strings in that persons Committees collection is contained within the 'committees' collection'. So 'p' is a person, and 's' is a string from that persons Committees collection.

Comment: As Magnus mentions, you might want to use the Intersect query because it will collect all of the distinct elements in 'committees' first, so will be faster unless you change the collection types for the Contains query.